# BluetoothDevice.createrfcommsockettoservicerecord is Null

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I have successfully recognised the bluetooth device (HC-05), I got its name, MAC address, and bond state, but when I'm trying to create a client socket in order to initiate a bluetooth connection with it I got a null socket.

```
//initializing bluetooth adapter
    val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
        val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
    }

    //creating a list of PAIRED DEVICES
    val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices

    //define a BluetoothDevice (the first on the list)
    pairedDevices?.forEach { device ->
        val deviceName = device.name
        val deviceHardwareAddress = device.address // MAC address
        val arduino: BluetoothDevice = pairedDevices.first()
```

Then:

```
val arduinoSocket = arduino?.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
```

which is Null.

My UUID is:

```
private val uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine for the most part.
Instead of using the default uuid, you can try using the code below to try and get the device's actual uuid.

```
BluetoothSocket arduinoSocket = arduino.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(arduino.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
```

Comment: That solved my problem, I indeed didn't get the right UUID, thank you! Να'σαι καλα φιλε!